# MediaRecorder start called in an invalid state: 0

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-mediarecorder

Brief description of the application:

User will click the start button on the MainActivity.java that will direct to FirstWord.java. On FirstWord.java, the user can record themselves saying a word by clicking on the record button. There is a text to speech instance that will output the pronunciation of a word.

The issues arises with the MediaRecorder. The application crashes once the user clicks on the recordButton.

FirstWord.java

The text to speech instance works properly, but I posted everything incase the textToSpeech is causing the MediaRecorder to fail.

```
package com.example.learnwords;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstWord extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

     private TextToSpeech myTTS;
     private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

        private static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        private static String audioFilePath;
        private static Button stopButton;
        private static Button playButton;
        private static Button recordButton;

        private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_word);   

        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

        recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        if (!hasMicrophone()) //calling hasMicrophone
        {
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            recordButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        audioFilePath = 
             Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                 + "/myaudio.3gp";  
    }
    protected boolean hasMicrophone() {
        PackageManager pmanager = this.getPackageManager();
        return pmanager.hasSystemFeature(
               PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
    }

    public void recordAudio(View view)throws Exception{
        isRecording = true;
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        recordButton.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
        mediaRecorder.start();
}
    public void stopClicked (View view)
    {   
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setEnabled(true);

        if (isRecording)
        {   
            recordButton.setEnabled(false);
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
            isRecording = false;
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            recordButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    public void playAudio (View view) throws IOException
    {
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        recordButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void speakWords(String speech) {
        //speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

            }
            else {
                    //no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }
        //setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
            //check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
        public void proClicked(View view) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String word = textView.getText().toString();
            speakWords(word);

        }
}
```

LogCat

```
09-19 11:17:20.229: D/ActivityThread(4603): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
09-19 11:17:20.229: D/ActivityThread(4603): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
09-19 11:17:20.229: D/ActivityThread(4603): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
09-19 11:17:20.680: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4603): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-19 11:17:20.720: E/(4603): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-19 11:17:20.720: E/(4603): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-19 11:17:22.061: V/MediaPlayer(4603): constructor
09-19 11:17:22.061: V/MediaPlayer(4603): setListener
09-19 11:17:22.241: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4603): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-19 11:17:24.363: I/TextToSpeech(4603): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
09-19 11:17:24.373: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4603): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-19 11:17:24.373: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4603): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-19 11:17:24.373: I/TextToSpeech(4603): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.GoogleTTSService}
09-19 11:17:28.998: W/System.err(4603): java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.media.MediaRecorder._setAudioSource(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:330)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at com.example.learnwords.FirstWord.recordAudio(FirstWord.java:75)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3674)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.018: W/System.err(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 11:17:29.028: W/System.err(4603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
09-19 11:17:29.028: W/System.err(4603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
09-19 11:17:29.028: W/System.err(4603):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.028: E/MediaRecorder(4603): start called in an invalid state: 0
09-19 11:17:29.028: W/dalvikvm(4603): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4196f438)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3679)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3674)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     ... 11 more
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at com.example.learnwords.FirstWord.recordAudio(FirstWord.java:83)
09-19 11:17:29.038: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     ... 14 more
```

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.learnwords"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.learnwords.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.learnwords.FirstWord"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_word"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.learnwords.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think those are the relevant files. If other files are needed, please comment.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Should you not use  `MediaPlayer.create(context, resid)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, int)

Comment: that may be true, but currently my problem is with the 'recordAudio' which uses MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out my mistake. I am missing permission statements in my AndroidManifest.XML.

```
<uses-permission 
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Those two lines are crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that mistake.you should not execute onClickListener.So startbutton and stope button both execute clickListener and call method for  playAudio and stop method stopClicked.

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try
                {startRecording(v);}catch (Exception e){}

            }
        });
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try
                {stopRecording(v);}catch (Exception e){}

            }
        });
```

I hope this code is helpful for you.